# QGIS crashes when trying to open ecw files

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, ecw

I added Ubuntugis unstable repo and installed Qgis, libgdal-ecw-src, libecwj2-3.3 but still does not work.

When I attempt to open an ecw file with Qgis it crashes and tells me:
'std::length_error': basic_string::_S_create

I am using ubuntu 13.04 and when I do:

gdalinfo --formats|grep -i ecw

it seems to work.

ECW (rw): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x)
JP2ECW (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 3.x)

What is the problem?

Comment: Hi, I have this problem too 
could you find a way to fix it?